# Merge on multiindex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I merge 2 multi-index dataframes? I get the error below.

```
df1              cola_df1  colb_df1
Fruit   1/1/20      2         3
        1/2/20      4         5
Apple   1/1/20      8         9
        1/2/20      10        11

df2              cola_df2  colb_df2
Fruit   1/1/20      2         3
        1/2/20      999       5
Apple   1/1/20      8         9
        1/2/20      10        11
```

```
df1              cola_df1  colb_df1  cola_df2  colb_df2
Fruit   1/1/20      2         3        2         3
        1/2/20      99         5      999         5
Apple   1/1/20      8         9        8          9
        1/2/20      10        11       10         11
```

I tried the following:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['x', 'y'], axis=1).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
cannot handle a non-unique multi-index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
indx =pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["Fruit", "Apple"],["1/1/20", "1/2/20"]], names=["x", "y"])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"cola_df1": [2,4,8,10], "colb_df1": [3,5,9,11]}, index=indx)
              cola_df1  colb_df1
x     y                         
Fruit 1/1/20         2         3
      1/2/20         4         5
Apple 1/1/20         8         9
      1/2/20        10        11
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"cola_df2": [2,999,8,10], "colb_df2": [3,5,9,11]}, index=indx)

df1.join(df2, on=["x", "y"], how="inner")
```

output

```
              cola_df1  colb_df1  cola_df2  colb_df2
x     y                                             
Fruit 1/1/20         2         3         2         3
      1/2/20         4         5       999         5
Apple 1/1/20         8         9         8         9
      1/2/20        10        11        10        11
```

where "x" and "y" are the names of the multi-indexes should work.
Check [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#joining-with-two-multiindexes) for further explanation.
`how="outer"` enables you to keep the indices (rows) that exist in one dataframe but do not exist in the other one.

Comment: Could you indicate why is that? you can check the link in the answer for more details.

Comment: no, I tried it with OP data and it worked fine. I suggest you to have a look at the link in my answer, because there you can see that `join` can be used to merge on two multiindex and more.

Comment: do you test OP solution?

Answer (score 2):

First is possible upgrade pandas? Because if using changed sample data like bellow I got different error if using your solution:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=['x','y'], axis=1).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
```

> ValueError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

---

Test if indexes are duplicated by:

```
print (df1.index.is_unique)
print (df2.index.is_unique)
```

You can deduplicated `MutliIndex` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print (df1)
              cola_df1  colb_df1
Fruit 1/1/20         2         3
      1/2/20         4         5
Apple 1/1/20         8         9
Fruit 1/2/20        10        11 <-duplicated index

print (df2)
              cola_df2  colb_df2
Fruit 1/1/20         2         3
      1/2/20       999         5
Apple 1/1/20         8         9
      1/2/20        10        11
      
print (df1.index.is_unique)
False

print (df2.index.is_unique)
True
```

---

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount()
df1 = df1.set_index('g', append=True)
df2 = df2.set_index('g', append=True)

df = pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=['x','y'], axis=1).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
               cola_df1 cola_df2 colb_df1 colb_df2
                      x        y        x        y
             g                                    
Apple 1/1/20 0      8.0      8.0      9.0      9.0
      1/2/20 0      NaN     10.0      NaN     11.0
Fruit 1/1/20 0      2.0      2.0      3.0      3.0
      1/2/20 0      4.0    999.0      5.0      5.0
             1     10.0      NaN     11.0      NaN <- added 1 only for duplicated
```

Comment: Thanks, but this generates a new index column, g, that is 0 throughout? So I still get the same error

Comment: @asd - I changed answer with sample data and some test if duplicated index. If still not working is possible upgrade pandas?

Comment: @asd - You are welcome! It seems you matching wrong answer `df1.join(df2, on=["x", "y"], how="inner") `, it cannot work here.